# What's the Numbers equivalent to Excel's "A1:A10-B1"

Tags: numbers

I'm switching from Microsoft Excel to Number.app, in Excel you can do

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A5-A1)^2,B1:B5)
```

the `a1:a10-b1` bit will return a cell range equivalent to `a1:a10` but with all the cells decremented by `b1`. What's the proper syntax in Numbers for that?

If I try to import an Excel workbook using that syntax into Numbers, that formula will be imported verbatim and Numbers will complain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In numbers, SUMPRODUCT (range, range…) takes the following arguments:

> range:   A range of cells. range is a reference to a single range of
> cells containing values of any type. If string or Boolean values are
> included in range, they are ignored.
>
> range…:   Optionally include one
> or more additional ranges of cells. The ranges must all have the same
> dimensions.

So you'll need to set up a range to perform the initial calculation (and squaring) and then sumproduct two simple ranges.

Comment: Also, Excel on the Mac was originally awesome, and although some of the last 8 years of versions were poor - the latest version is quite excellent as a Mac app as well as in implementing most of what a Windows user might expect like pivot tables and super complicated flexibility.

Comment: well, I already know how to do it by having "extra" cell ranges with the intermediate results. I was wondering if there was something similar to the excel "shortcut" notation for it.

Comment: There isn't but I wanted to at least explain why. The site doesn't work well when someone answers a question as "No."  I suppose I could have commented and asked why you thought that this was something numbers could do, but that's also not so constructive.